# After mapping a type to an integral value, how do I get the type back given an integral value?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build this Entity Component System, I have this templated container class that I use to store all Components types, and for every passed type the code below is in charge to map the type to an index, so that I can use it as the Key into a std::map (where the Values are pointers to "vector"). So for example a call to `typeId<RectComponent>()`maybe return a value 2, assuming the typeId class was instantiated 2 times before with other template arguments:

```cpp
#pragma once
using uInt = size_t;

class typeIdBase
{
private:
    static uInt internal_generateTypeID() {
        static uInt typeIDCounter{};
        return typeIDCounter++;
    }    template<typename T> friend class typeId;
};

template<typename T>
class typeId {
public:
    operator uInt() const { return id; }
private:
    static inline uInt id = typeIdBase::internal_generateTypeID();
};
```

The problem is that now I also need to go the opposite direction, I need a type back given a size_t value, so for instance in my code `typename idType<2>::type`should give the equivalent of typing `RectComponent`.
 Following the example above with RectComponent associated to value 2, `typeId<typename idType<2>::type>()` should return `2` as well, just to make it clear.
I am stuck and no idea how to get there, any suggestions?

Comment: Not with this trick, I think. You will need to write out all the types and numbers somewhere. Or make a script to generate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right when you do

```
typeId<typename idType<2>::type>()
```

you're asking the compiler to instantiate a template with a template parameter value which is not known at compile time. And this just doesn't work in C++. Templates are just code blueprints for the compiler, and for each different set of parameters they are instantiated with, there is one version of the templated code with the concrete types that is actually compiled in the translation unit. At runtime, none of this template stuff exists, you only have the different instantiated versions and that's it.

So this type of implementation can't work. Depending on what your problem really is, you will have to provide such a mapping at compile time, or find an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be very careful with static initializers like in your example, because the id of a given type might change during compilations.

Unfortunately there is no way to map back the index to the type - as @user253751 already commented.

Because you stated you want to use the index as a key for a map, i would recommend to use [`type_index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) instead.

This allows you to use the type directly as key for a map.
If you want to store an array of widgets for a given type, you could use something along the lines of:

[Live Demo for Testing](https://www.onlinegdb.com/rkWECy_aS)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <typeindex>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class WidgetMap {
public:
  template<typename T>
  void addWidget(const T& val) {
    auto idx = std::type_index(typeid(T));
    if(m_map.find(idx) == m_map.end())
      m_map[idx] = std::make_shared<std::vector<T>>();

    auto vecPtr = std::static_pointer_cast<std::vector<T>>(m_map[idx]);
    vecPtr->push_back(val);
  }

  template<typename T>
  std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>> getWidgets() {
    auto idx = std::type_index(typeid(T));
    auto it = m_map.find(idx);
    if(it == m_map.end())
      throw std::runtime_error(std::string{"No widget stored for type "} + typeid(T).name());

    return std::static_pointer_cast<std::vector<T>>(it->second);
  }

private:
  std::map<std::type_index, std::shared_ptr<void>> m_map;
};
```

Then you can use your widget types as key:

```cpp
struct ExampleWidget {
  std::string message;
};


// Usage:
WidgetMap m;

// Add widgets    
m.addWidget(ExampleWidget{"Hello"});
m.addWidget(ExampleWidget{"World"});

// retrieve widgets by type
auto exampleWidgets = m.getWidgets<ExampleWidget>();
for(auto& val : *exampleWidgets)
  std::cout << val.message << std::endl;
```

Comment: This my code can already do, I can do `getVector<RectComponent>()` and get a vector, what I need in this corresponding example would be given a `std::type_index` it should give me a corresponding type.
Because if you imagine an entity with a `std::map<std::type_index, size_t> componentsId` that only store the id for components of course I want to be able to access specific components if needed, but at destruction I want a range for loop trough that map that can convert the type_index to the correct type so to access the  correct vector and remove the component.